# guardar en database firebase los datos de registro y el token

Tags: java, android, base-de-datos, firebase

Tengo una app android y los usuarios se deben registrar y los datos me llegan a una base de datos de firebase, pero quiero que en el mismo conjunto de datos esté guardado el token de este usuario para poder enviarle notificaciones individuales a este usuario.

Este código que tengo me funciona pero no como yo quiero. Cuando el usuario se registra en la base de datos, se están guardando los datos del usuario pero el token se guarda en otra parte diferente y no he logrado que todo quede junto.

El código relevante es:

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnSuccessListener( RegistroFirebase.this,  new OnSuccessListener<InstanceIdResult>() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(InstanceIdResult instanceIdResult) {
                    String newToken = instanceIdResult.getToken();

                    Log.e("newToken",newToken);

                    persona p = new persona();
                    p.setAA_Token(newToken);                    
                    databaseReference.child("1_Usuarios_Registrados").child(p.getAA_Token()).setValue(p);

                }
            });

            persona p = new persona();
            p.setUid(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            p.setA_Nombre(contenidoNombre);
            p.setB_Apellido(contenidoApellido);
            p.setC_Correo(email);
            p.setD_Celular(contenidoCelular);
            databaseReference.child("1_Usuarios_Registrados").child(p.getUid()).setValue(p);
```

---

osea. si un usuario se registra en la app todo funciona bien. y en la base de dato se crea 2 registros.

1 registro con los datos del usuario y otro registro con el token.

lo que yo quiero es que se cree solo un registro donde este todo junto, los datos personales y el token.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muestra las capturas de pantalla donde se está guardando cada cosa, no se entiende bien la pregunta y una parte del código es confusa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que estas creando dos objetos persona, por lo tanto el token que al principio solicitas no lo estas guardando en el mismo objeto, por ende cuando mandas todo al usuario ese token al ser del otro objeto no lo esta mandando

```
final persona p = new persona(); //Creamos un solo objeto de tipo persona

FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnSuccessListener( RegistroFirebase.this, new OnSuccessListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(InstanceIdResult instanceIdResult) {
                String newToken = instanceIdResult.getToken();

                Log.e("newToken",newToken);

                p.setAA_Token(newToken);    // le asignamos el token una vez lo tengamos               
                databaseReference.child("1_Usuarios_Registrados").child(p.getAA_Token()).setValue(p);

        p.setUid(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        p.setA_Nombre(contenidoNombre);
        p.setB_Apellido(contenidoApellido);
        p.setC_Correo(email);
        p.setD_Celular(contenidoCelular);
        databaseReference.child("1_Usuarios_Registrados").child(p.getUid()).setValue(p);

            }
        });
```

Recordá que al ser una llamada asyncrona primero vas a tener que esperar a que el token regrese, una vez que tengas el token y lo setees al objeto persona , ahi podes construir tu objeto completo y mandarlo al usuario, si lo haces como lo tenes ahora lo que va a pasar es que se va a crear el objeto persona, en x momento en el tiempo va a asignar ese token y puede que anteriormente a asignar ese token ya haya mandado los datos del usuario sin ese token, por eso ahora lo que hacemos es primero solicitar el token, una vez lo tenemos lo seteamos a la persona y por ultimo creamos todo el objeto y lo mandamos a firebase como una operación atómica

Comment: olle pero si saco el objeto persona y solo creo uno como tu me explicaste. entonces este objeto esta quedando fuera de donde obtengo el token y por lo tanto no lo toma como variable. osea me saca este error. Variable 'p' is accesed from inner class, needs to be declared final

Comment: si, tenes que declararla final como final persona p = new persona()

Comment: ya me funciona todo. pero a la base de datos no se sube el token. ya subí el código en otro comentario por si puedes verlo y ayudarme. gracias

Comment: Hola, te sugiero que hagas otra pregunta y no agregues una respuesta como ora pregunta, ya que puede confundir a las personas que ingresen con la misma duda, puedes aceptar esta respuesta si te funcionó y formular la otra en la cual no te está andando el token, un saludo